# Pypy: pip install lxml

Tags: python, linux, lxml, pypy

I am trying to install pypy 2.6.1 into a virtual env. I have followed the instructions here: http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html that worked ok. But trouble is when i was trying to install some other things into the virtualenv. One of them had lxml as a dependency and this is what happened:

> ```
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4276:68: error: ‘PyThreadState’ has no member named ‘c_tracefunc’
>                    (tstate->c_profilefunc || (CYTHON_TRACE && tstate->c_tracefunc))) {\
>                                                                     ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:34578:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_TraceCall’
>    __Pyx_TraceCall("_htmlNameIsValid", __pyx_f[4], 1596, 0, {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[4]; __pyx_lineno = 1596; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;});
>    ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4284:26: error: ‘PyThreadState’ has no member named ‘use_tracing’
>        if (unlikely(tstate->use_tracing) && !tstate->tracing &&\
>                           ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:555:43: note: in definition of macro ‘unlikely’
>    #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
>                                            ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:34578:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_TraceCall’
>    __Pyx_TraceCall("_htmlNameIsValid", __pyx_f[4], 1596, 0, {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[4]; __pyx_lineno = 1596; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;});
>    ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4284:51: error: ‘PyThreadState’ has no member named ‘tracing’
>        if (unlikely(tstate->use_tracing) && !tstate->tracing &&\
>                                                    ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:34578:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_TraceCall’
>    __Pyx_TraceCall("_htmlNameIsValid", __pyx_f[4], 1596, 0, {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[4]; __pyx_lineno = 1596; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;});
>    ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4285:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ has no member named ‘c_profilefunc’
>                (tstate->c_profilefunc || (CYTHON_TRACE && tstate->c_tracefunc))) {\
>                       ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:34578:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_TraceCall’
>    __Pyx_TraceCall("_htmlNameIsValid", __pyx_f[4], 1596, 0, {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[4]; __pyx_lineno = 1596; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;});
>    ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4285:64: error: ‘PyThreadState’ has no member named ‘c_tracefunc’
>                (tstate->c_profilefunc || (CYTHON_TRACE && tstate->c_tracefunc))) {\
>                                                                 ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:34578:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_TraceCall’
>    __Pyx_TraceCall("_htmlNameIsValid", __pyx_f[4], 1596, 0, {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[4]; __pyx_lineno = 1596; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;});
>    ^
> src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4342:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ has no member named ‘use_tracing’
> ```

This is just a sample, there seem to be millions and millions of lines like this. It scrolls so fast I can't see what the first error is and it never seems to end.

I have seen this question and answer: [how to install lxml with pypy in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037435/how-to-install-lxml-with-pypy-in-virtualenv) it does not help. I have also seen the additional question and answer linked from there [How can I set up lxml and pypy on Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675625/how-can-i-set-up-lxml-and-pypy-on-yosemite) (It's for yoesmite pypy 2.4 and this is for pypy 2.6 and linux) and that doesn't work either.

Has anyone else seen there errors.